# Calculating Pot Odds on multiple re-raises

Tags: texas-hold-em, nlhe, odds, pre-flop

NLHE: Suppose you are on a small suited connector (6s5s) on BB and want to see the flop for cheap. How do you deal with 2 villains who keep re-raising each other one BB at a time, giving you good odds with each call, but end up making you put much more money into the pot than you intended to with those hole cards.

Villains may be colluding or otherwise, but i don't think its relevant what their intentions are at this point.

Is there something wrong with the math here? Or does it really make sense to follow them all the way with each call.

Comment: Are you talking limit, or no-limit? Because with limit, there is usually a limit to the number of raises allowed per round.

Comment: This would be no limit. I believe in tourney play there is no limit for the number of re-raises as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediate odds to call a single bet/raise is not the same as overall pot odds.

Count the number of players in the pot.  3 players the overall pot odds is 2:1 (plus any overlays from folded hands).

You were getting 9:2 on the first call so it looks very attractive if the was a limp and a mid raise.  But betting is not capped.  I think you need to release. 
If you call you would likely get re-raised.  At that point you are likely up against bigger suited overs, AK, or over pairs.  You are a 4:1 dog and have to pay more to see a river.  Even if you hit then it is hard to get paid off.

Comment: hmm i never thought of considering the villains' cards. Great insight thanks!

Comment: Going to flop 2 pair of better 5.6%

Answer (score 1):

Lets stop for a sec and think about your hand before calculating any odds. There is a right way (+EV) to play suited connectors and wrong way (-EV). Our goal is to play plus EV game, and our decision should be based on that. So you have 65s on BB - and there is  a raise and reraise in front of you. You are out of position assuming they both in position relative to you so it is -EV to call here whatever odds are: the number of times you will lose small bets will be more than one big win when you get lucky to hit big. You rarely flop flushes or straights and mostly you will flop draws, and that is where position is a crucial advantage - out of position you might have to pay big to chase your draws and you might never hit it. The situation is different let say when you are on button. Even with a raise and a reraise in front of you I would still call if we are deep enough. As a rule of thumb I call if it takes between 5% and 10% depending you strong my hands is and how aggressive my opponents play flop and turn. In position I can even steal it on later streets when a board get scary and not fitting their ranges. So before calculating odds you have to consider all other variables: position, stack depth, opponents.